# Is there a torque wrench you can use a "Cheater Bar" on?

Tags: torque

Do there exist torque wrenches whose accuracy would not be affected by the use of a "cheater bar"? [https://www.teamtorque.com/frequently-asked-questions#:~:text=Q%3A%20Can%20I%20Use%20A,serious%20bodily%20injury%20may%20result](https://www.teamtorque.com/frequently-asked-questions#:%7E:text=Q%3A%20Can%20I%20Use%20A,serious%20bodily%20injury%20may%20result).

I found the below website that describes "non-length dependent" torque wrench tech. Would using a cheater bar on such a wrench still be problematic?

https://www.heamar.co.uk/blog/88_click-vs-cam-over-torque-technology

What about a beam style torque wrench?

Comment: So just use a 2 meter long bar, or 3 metres and a set of pull scales. So many kilogrammes at a distance X. Done that before and no damage to any torque wrench. or go to a shop that does heavy trucks and they have torque wrenches that are 6ft long and do some 800lbft. Needs a man to carry and use it...

Comment: it does not affect use, per se,  but it can damage it, which would make it useless

Comment: jsotola, why does google say the following then: https://www.teamtorque.com/frequently-asked-questions#:~:text=Q%3A%20Can%20I%20Use%20A,serious%20bodily%20injury%20may%20result.

Comment: @AdrianBeltran that's the "damage" region ... if a person is not strong enough to tighten a bolt to the required torque,  then a cheater bar would help, as long as the capacity of the torque wrench is not exceeded

Answer (score 5):

#### As long as the force/torque is the same, the wrench doesn't care how it is applied.

A beam wrench would be affected if the cheater extended past the handle; beam types depend on the torque being at the handle since you're measuring deflection.

The reality is that torque wrenches are sized to the force you can put on it without a cheater.  It does no good to use a cheater to get a torque wrench to put 800 ft-lbs (1088 Nm) on a fastener if the wrench only goes to 250.  You're better off using a breaker bar then and not ruining your torque wrench.

The authors of the page referenced don't seem to understand how force is transmitted through a tube.